# is mongo stored javascript good solution to multiple DB inserts in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-populate

I have a functionality is Mean Stack which has multiple collection inserts and creation. If it do that in plain mongoose , its going to be multiple Mongo calls and it might be slow.
Can i use mongo stored javascript for this?Pass some values to mongo javascript and it can do all the things from there.. 
Is it a suggested approach?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to do lots of inserts is to use the [Bulk Write Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) feature. You can define a set of inserts to be done as a single batch, then pass them all to MongoDB in one go.

However, that is really only appropriate for jobs such as a big data take-on, where you are importing a large number of similar records in one go. If you are running a normal application where there might be inserts, updates, deletes and reads in varying proportions and at varying rates, you would be better off letting Mongoose submit them as individual queries, and making sure your server hardware can cope.

Comment: I dont have too much insertions.. Its a clone document kind of feature where data has to be read from multiple collections and alter some values and insert as a new document.. maximum 10 different collection and may be 20-30 documents has to be inserted. What do u suggest for this?

Comment: 20-30 inserts? That's not a lot of data, so you'll probably be fine just doing them as normal.